# $facebook->api() always fails and throws name lookup timeout exception

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I m creating FB application using new graph api(iframe). Application works fine but when I call api method it throws exception. Say call to

```
$permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
OR
$fbme     =   $facebook->api('/me');
```

always fails and throws "Name lookup timeout" exception. So I browse for this problem and found one solution that is changing facebook.php file in that set CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT from default 10 to higher value. But this solution doesn't work for me and I m getting same problem. Why this is happening. Is there any solution for this problem or any alternate method for api() on serverside.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the new graph API?

You might try replacing "api-read.facebook.com" with "api.facebook.com" in the library you downloaded from facebook. (I think it's name is facebook.php)

And sometimes the Facebook server is not running 100%, you can check that here:
http://api-status.com/6404/50042/Facebook-Graph-API

Also you should check your config, maybe you didn't set the correct App Id or Secret key.